# Flutter/macOS - Application still contains the default signing identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, flutter

I recently copied some files from the `iOS` folder in an old flutter project to a new project so that I could preserve `appIcons` and `launchScreens`. Now I get the following error when trying to launch my code from **VSCode**, **Xcode works fine**.

I'm wondering if there's a way that I can just change certain parameters so that my signing id can be replaced, but I can't find anywhere in Xcode to do so.

(Nokia 3310 is just an iPhone 6 I use for debug testing :) )

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Nokia 3310 in debug mode...
    Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: **********
    Xcode build done.
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    Xcode's output:
    ↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    Target 'Pods-Runner' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods-Runner.a' because its architectures 'arm64' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 arm64'
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Runner/main.m:1:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:37:
    In file included from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
    /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:80:42: warning: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationSettings [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings*)notificationSettings;
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:43:12: note: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject
    ^
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Runner/main.m:1:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:37:
    In file included from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
    /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:140:58: warning: this block declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)())completionHandler;
    ^
    void
    2 warnings generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.h:1:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:37:
    In file included from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
    /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:80:42: warning: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationSettings [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings*)notificationSettings;
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:8:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:43:12: note: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject
    ^
    While building module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.h:1:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/Flutter.h:37:
    In file included from /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:11:
    /Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:140:58: warning: this block declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
    completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)())completionHandler;
    ^
    void
    2 warnings generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/flutter/ios'
    ld: library not found for -lPods-Runner
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/jake/Desktop/cryptick-master/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/flutter/ios'
    ld: library not found for -lPods-Runner
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

    Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
    It appears that your application still contains the default signing identifier.
    Try replacing 'com.example' with your signing id in Xcode:
      open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
    Error launching application on Nokia 3310.
    Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: This isn't an answer but a FWIW: I've found the following package helpful when working with icons (as for launch screen, I usually use the drag and drop interface of Xcode): https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have a working file for icons and the launch screen. In this case it's mainly just that I deleted the old files that I replaced so I can't just go back and start from scratch. The package looks good though I'll keep it in bookmarks :)

Comment: 2 years later and I'm facing this issue too. Did you solved it?

Comment: @lucasjr I'm gonna take another look at this and try to find a solid answer, in the meantime I think I just started a new project, migrated my code, icons etc by copying my code and rebuilding my `appIcons` and `launchScreens` directories with my desired assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue has been solved by creating a new project again and migrating the code. With the current details, I'm unable to replicate this issue on my end.

If someone else is having similar issues, please provide the steps to replicate the behavior and file it here: [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/%C2%A0)